# Styles applied directly to an element are lost when those styles moved into .CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Start with this:

```
    <div class="mainContent" style="color:white; overflow-y: auto; position:fixed; top:210px; bottom:60px;">
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUs"        style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsOmni"    style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsVerify"  style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsSelf"    style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsHow"     style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
```

And this .css file content:

```
.mainContent {

    width: 850px; 
    xmargin-left:1%;
    border: 1px solid silver; 
    background:transparent url(../images/mainContentOverlay.png);

    -moz-border-radius:     6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  6px;
    -khtml-border-radius:   6px;
    border-radius:          6px;

}
```

**And everything is just fine.**

But when I take the style applied directly to the DIV and move it into the .css file (and remove the style attr from the div), the form collapses into chaos.

And, yes, I have at the top:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

... and all the *other* styles it provides are working just fine also.

Any idea what is wrong?

I have already looked at this, without success:
[Why do CSS styles only take affect when placed in a style tag in my form and not in the associated CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784384/why-do-css-styles-only-take-affect-when-placed-in-a-style-tag-in-my-form-and-not)

**EDIT:**

Folks have asked for the "after code" for comparison.  I didn't include it originally because it seemed pretty easy to visualize the result.  But here is the AFTER version:

```
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUs"        style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsOmni"    style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsVerify"  style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsSelf"    style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsHow"     style="display:none"></div>
    </div>


.mainContent {

    color:white; overflow-y: auto; position:fixed; top:210px; bottom:60px;
    width: 850px; 
    xmargin-left:1%;
    border: 1px solid silver; 
    background:transparent url(../images/mainContentOverlay.png);

    -moz-border-radius:     6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  6px;
    -khtml-border-radius:   6px;
    border-radius:          6px;

}
```

Comment: Is rule `xmargin-left:1%;` a hack?

Comment: kinda flying blind here, but is your href correct?

Comment: Please show us  your HTML without inline styles.

Comment: xmargin is just me killing that attribute without actually removing it - in case I want it back later.  I'm assuming css will just harmlessly ignore it.  Actually, it does ignore it.  This style works just fine without causing any errors.

Comment: Jeremy, not to be obtuse about it, but it's not hard to imagine that div without that style="" attribute on it.

Comment: The minimum test case posted seems to work fine in Firefox (both before and after versions look the same). But you mention "the form" collapses into chaos. Could you verify the test case fails pls?

Comment: Traktor53:

Before, with styles applied inline on the DIV: http://imgur.com/YPU1B5L

After, with style moved to .CSS file : http://imgur.com/sbNYBax

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing the in line style of the div in the .mainContent class of your external stylesheet?

If yes, maybe try rapping the .mainContent div in a parent div and apply the in line style to the parent div, also I think you might have an error in your .mainContent div, shouldn't xmargin-left be margin-left?

Answer (score 0):

xmargin-left is not a css property. Chances are that the rendering engine hits that, dont know what to do with it, and stops rendering any css below it.

Perhaps a typo and should be `margin-left` ?

If you are trying to comment it out, use the proper css comment syntax of

```
/* comments here */
```

Comment: I have completely removed the xmargin rule.  No joy.

Comment: I sometimes simply change a css attribute to something non-existent in lieu of removing it entirely.  That way, I can see what I've tried and not forget it.  And, I can re-enable it if necessary.  Just in case doing so actually BREAKS css (kind of like the way that an error in js kills the entire script and everything in it) I removed the xmargin style entirely, without success.  :-(

Comment: It is best to just comment it out if you are unsure if you will need the rule later. Don't create faux DOM properties in your CSS. You can really screw up your layout and functionality.

That said, I took your updated script and threw it in a Fiddle and it seems to work fine (minus the missing background image):
https://jsfiddle.net/afj3np42/

You have something else going on. Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Some points :

1.In some situation href="css/style.css" can be case sensitive so if your file is 'Css/style.css' (with capital C) it may not work.
Try to see whether css/style.css file is accessible in you browser or not.

2.The priory of styles and .css files depends on where to place them.
The latest place has the more priority.

if you do somthing like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="c1.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="c2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

and

```
   <div class='a_c1css_style  a_c2css_style'></div>
   <div class='a_c2css_style  a_c1css_style'></div>
```

Both DIVs have the same result because c2.css is used after c1.css in the page.