# Is there a way to do global event binding on dynamic HTML loaded via jQuery .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page that uses jQuery .load() to pull in HTML from other files.  I do this mostly for readability purposes.

I ran into a problem whereby code that is loaded via .load() is not "visible" to other javascript loaded later in the module because .load() is asynchronous.  This was solved in another StackOverflow question of mine with very good results, by doing the .click() binding in the .load() callback.  S.O. shone through like it always does!

Now, I have another question that is also related.

HTML:

```
        <div class="mainContent" style="color:white; overflow-y: auto; position:fixed; top:210px; bottom:60px;">
            <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUs"        style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsCompany" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsVerify"  style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsSelf"    style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="linkContent" id="contentAboutUsHow"     style="display:none"></div>
        </div>
```

jQuery ready() function:

```
$("#contentAboutUs").load("contentAboutUs.html");
$("#contentAboutUsCompany").load("contentAboutUsCompany.html");
$("#contentAboutUsVerify").load("contentAboutUsVerify.html");
$("#contentAboutUsSelf").load("contentAboutUsSelf.html", function () { $(".saveButton").click(function () { saveForm(); })  });
$("#contentAboutUsHow").load("contentAboutUsHow.html");
```

You will notice that on the AboutUsSelf .load(), a callback binds the click event of the ".saveButton" to a function called saveForm().  This works perfectly, and was the answer I got from my previous S.O. question.

As you see, ".saveButton" is a class, and in fact, this button will be on MANY pages of the form; which is why it is a class and not an ID.

The question then is this:  I do not want to do this click() binding on every section that contains one of these buttons.  Is there a way to dynamically .load() this HTML, and yet apply this click() binding globally instead of doing it in the .load() callback individually in every case where it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading these inside a container, you can use that.

```
$('.mainContent').on('click','.saveButton', function(){
     saveForm();
});
```

Event handlers bound this way bind to the container and it "looks within" for the selector of the button.  You cannot directly bind to the class for the button as it has nothing to bind to until it is loaded and in the DOM.

Bind to the closest container (not document for instance) that you can to avoid the deep "look within" impact with a super large DOM.

Note that one thing you also experience here is multiple hits to your sever - i.e. you would benefit from the cache of the HTML if it were in the page already and it only hits the page once that way.  That being said, dynamic page portions are a good candidate for this type binding at the container level.

With ASP.NET MVC for instance these can be put in partial views and get in the page prior to hitting the browser.

You did not ask but I would also move the style to a CSS file and not put it in the markup - this then makes your markup much cleaner and easier to modify.

Comment: The CSS styling issue was the subject of another of my questions regarding this same code that never got an answer that worked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820179/styles-applied-directly-to-an-element-are-lost-when-those-styles-moved-into-css

I will try your solution and let you know if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked perfectly.  ALL the .saveButton buttons on the form now respond to the click event, just as I wanted!  Thank you!

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace I looked over the CSS question, it is likely a matter of specificity in the CSS where the in-line overrides others so adding more specificity or the less desirable !Important might address the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Essentially, what you can do is bind your event listener, using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), to a containing element instead of directly on the element you're listening to. Relevant info:

> If we were to click our newly added item, nothing would happen. This is because of the directly bound event handler that we attached previously. Direct events are only attached to elements at the time the .on() method is called. In this case, since our new anchor did not exist when .on() was called, it does not get the event handler.

Example:

```
$("#container-of-some-sort").on("click", ".saveButton", function(){ 
    saveForm(); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) - should be able to attach your click event there and have it apply to all the new buttons loaded in